# Extract all values when I have key : value and store all value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array,I want to extract each values in each line (values after (***:***) )

```
Array =
0:Object {node-input-audio_services1: "79388", audio_ip: "127.0.0.1", audio_port_1: "7654"}
1:Object {node-input-video_services1: "80788", video_ip: "127.0.0.1", video_port_1: "7654"}
2:Object {node-input-audio_services1: "4fe10"}
3:Object {node-input-video_services1: "4fe10"}
```

Imagine I have several key : value then I want to extract Just value like bellow:

```
Array =
0:Object {key1 : "value" , Key2 : "value2" , key3: "value3"}
1:Object {key1 : "value5" , Key2 : "value6" , key3: "value7"}
```

I have the result like this :

```
var result = ["value","value2",value3","value5","value6","value7"];
```

The problem is, I can't use (key1.array) because each time in my program have one key's name.I really new in JavaScript and don't know how I can start

Comment: `let array = Object.values(obj);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in conjunction with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get *all* the values from your array of objects:

```js
const arr = [{
    key1: "value",
    Key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
  },
  {
    key1: "value5",
    Key2: "value6",
    key3: "value7"
  }
];

let result = arr.reduce(
  (c, v) => c.concat(Object.values(v)), []
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map through each object in your array and use the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method to extract each value like this:

```
const result = Array.map(e => Object.values(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping through the array and concat the values like so

`results = results.concat( Object.values( yourArray[loopIndex] ) )`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
    key1: "value",
    Key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
  },
  {
    key1: "value5",
    Key2: "value6",
    key3: "value7"
  }
];

let out = arr.reduce(
  (c, v) => c.concat(Object.values(v)), []
);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: You don't need to post a copy of the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{ndeInput_audio_services1: "79388", audio_ip: "127.0.0.1", audio_port_1: "7654"},
           {nodeInput_video_services1: "80788", video_ip: "127.0.0.1", video_port_1: "7654"},
           {nodeInput_audio_services1: "4fe10"},
           {nodeInput_video_services1: "4fe10"}];
```

If we have an array of objects like the ones you showed, I would use the underscore library and the .values() function that can be applied to an array. Here is an example (underscore is denoted by the _ symbol):

```
var result = [];

_.map(arr, obj => _.each(_.values(obj), val => result.push(val)));
```

first, we create an empty array to store the result. Next we map through each object in the array. We then return the VALUE associated with each object in the array. We then push that value to the result array. The result will be all of the values associated with each key in the array:

```
console.log(result);

[
  '79388',     '127.0.0.1',
  '7654',      '80788',
  '127.0.0.1', '7654',
  '4fe10',     '4fe10'
]
```

Comment: when use your method I give this error : _ is not defined

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that you’ll need to use the “underscore” library. The _ symbol is just a variable that stores the “underscore” module that you need to use. If you’re getting a not defined error it means that you didn’t define _ as a variable whos value is the underscore module.